# RC Car through PARALLEL PORT

Tags: c#, hardware

I'am making project, in which i'am controlling a remote control car from PC using parallel port...
I want to know whether there is any library or code in C# which could help me in resolving this problem using window form application.....
I'am using transistor for this propose

Answer (score 2):

There are a few resources out there for controlling ports with .net code:

Here's a great article on codeproject: [I/O Ports Uncensored - 1 - Controlling LEDs (Light Emiting Diodes) with Parallel Port](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csppleds.aspx)

And here's a good place to find lots of info (and inpout32.dll as well): http://www.lvr.com/parport.htm